# How to get the internet connection speed with objective c in mac os sdk

Tags: objective-c

I need to get the internet connection speed for the connected internet connection with objective c in Mac OS Application.

Comment: you actually need to transfer file(s) of known size and measure how long it took.

Answer (score 3):

There's no "formal" way to do this. Also note that in practice "internet connection speed" makes very little sense. You probably mean "max bandwidth to your nearest gateway", but in a more general fashion it doesn't make much sense (think router with several network interfaces for instance).

Anyway, you won't find any API to do this. You're better off just optimizing for the "worst case scenario", and it will just go faster if the user has more bandwidth.

Also note that you might be able to tell if the iOS device is on WiFi or 3G though.